# JavaFX: Returns NullPointerException when opening a new pane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm working on a project that will have a stage with two screens. One for a cart and the other for a checkout. The idea is that a single stage will hold a pane to load the FXML files for each screen of these screens. The stage itself opens fine but the issue comes from trying to open ether of the individual panes. I'm building the code on the singleton approach since only one of these stages should be open at any given time.

Below is the code for the OrderStageController

```
package Controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OrderStageController {
    static OrderStageController instance = null;
    public Stage cartStage=new Stage();
    Parent root;
    @FXML Pane paneOrder;

    public static OrderStageController getInstance(){ return instance; }

    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        instance=this;
        openCartPane();
    }

    public void openCartStage() throws Exception{
        root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML_Files/OrderStage.fxml"));
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,655,555);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/FXML_Files/test.css").toExternalForm());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/FXML_Files/login.css").toExternalForm());
        cartStage.setTitle("Placeholder");
        cartStage.setScene(scene);
        cartStage.show();
    }

    public void openCartPane() throws IOException {
        Pane paneCart=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML_Files/MyCartScreen.fxml"));
        paneOrder.getChildren().clear();
        paneOrder.getChildren().add(paneCart);
    }

    public void openCheckoutPane() throws IOException {
        Pane paneCheckout=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML_Files/CheckoutScreen.FXML"));
        paneOrder.getChildren().clear();
        paneOrder.getChildren().add(paneCheckout);
    }
}
```

This is a currently empty controller for the CartController. I haven't added anything yet since I can't even get it to open. I'm including it just in case there's something wrong with it.

```
package Controllers;

public class MyCartController {
    // Classes
    OrderStageController orderStageController=OrderStageController.getInstance();
}
```

The FXML files are fine. Everything is where it's supposed to be and they run fine on their own.

The issue arises when I attempt to open the stage and the initializer method tries to run the "openCartPane" method. I receive a NullPointerException stating that the orderPane is a null value.

The stack trace a I get is this

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8885)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3890)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1885)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2618)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Joshua/JAVA/Fall20_FoodOrdering/out/production/SeniorProject/FXML_Files/OrderStage.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at Controllers.OrderStageController.openCartStage(OrderStageController.java:25)
    at Controllers.MainStageController.openCartPane(MainStageController.java:46)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2591)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Controllers.OrderStageController.openCartPane(OrderStageController.java:36)
    at Controllers.OrderStageController.initialize(OrderStageController.java:21)
    ... 77 more
```

The error seems to be specifically happening because of the line `paneOrder.getChildren().clear();` in the `openCartPane()` method. I've been running tests on it for a while now and I can't find the cause on my own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ADDITON

I've done some more digging in the debugger and found these variable values at the moment of the crash.

[image]

They haven't shed much light on the issue for me but maybe it'll be helpful to someone.

Comment: You're getting `NullPointerException` because paneOrder is `null` you didn't instanciate it

Comment: @Lyes I've tried creating an instance of a Pane class and I still get NullPointer error. I don't think that's the source of the error.

Comment: Then be sure it has the same name as in the FXML file

Comment: I double checked everything and somehow, InteliJ pulled from git and set the name of the pane in FXML to the name it had a couple of days ago. I overlooked it during my troubleshooting. Changed the name it worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Our git server has been acting strangely for a while now but it's never caused an issue that lasted this long. I'm going to be spending the day tomorrow fixing it once and for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Lyes. The issue turned out to be a renamed variable in the controller's FXML file. Git and my obliviousness were the culprits.

Comment: Don't blame git :-)

Comment: Normally I wouldn't, but we've been dealing with a mess on our server for a while and it simply refuses to behave.